# Retrofit path replacements: replacement over whole path (including /)

Tags: android, retrofit

In my setup, I get all the paths for my resources from the REST API from an initial call to the API. We use this pattern to be able to change all the resource paths without breaking all existing app versions in the process.

I have been playing around with Retrofit and I tried to create a method that would accept any path I pass to it as a string. My try looks like this

```
@GET("/{path}")
public FooBar getFooBar(@Path("path") String path);
```

I then try to call it as follows.

```
String path = "foo/bar";
api.getFooBar(path);
```

Unfortunately Retrofit URL-Encodes the path replacement and I end up making a request to `/foo%2Fbar` instead of `/foo/bar`. Is there any way to disable URL-Encoding for path replacements or to make replacements spanning multiple path segments? Unfortunately I don't even know how many path segments there are, it is all controlled by the API.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [`@EncodedPath`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/EncodedPath.html)! That's it. I'll copy the Javadoc so this answer has more meat:

> Named replacement in the URL path. Values are converted to string using `String.valueOf(Object)`. Values are used literally without URL encoding. See `@Path` for URL encoding equivalent.

Use it like this:

> ```
> @GET("/{path}")
> void example(@EncodedPath("path") String path, ..);
> ```

Comment: I can't try it right now, but since it is so painfully obvious, I'll just trust you and accept the answer. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: I think that `@EncodedPath` has been deprecated now.

Comment: Yes. As of 1.7.0 you can use `@Path` and one of its flags.

Comment: @GET("/user/{name}")
 void notEncoded(@Path(value="name", encode=false) String name);

Comment: None of the above solutions works with Retrofit 2.0. I created an issue for this at https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1364

Comment: Use  @Code_Life solution, as  ```@EncodedPath``` was deprecated. Use ```@Path(value = "link", encode = false) String link```

Answer (score 24):

Since @EncodedPath is deprecated now

Retrofit 1.9:

```
@GET("/{path}")
void example(@Path(value = "path", encoded = false) String path, ..);
```

Retrofit 2.*:

```
@GET("/{path}")
void example(@Path(value = "path", encoded = false) String path, ..);
```

Comment: It worked for me, but I changed encoded=true, in retrofit 2.3.

Comment: the encoded flag actually means this:
true - I did the encoding myself thank you very much

false - do the encoding for me please.

which ambiguous to say the least!

Comment: even with `encoded = true`, Retrofit keeps encoding the url in my tests

Answer (score 12):

There are known bugs, and you can watch the bugreport on:
[Retrofit @Github](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1168)

There is also a link to possible solutions: [Solution @Github](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/1887e011a119190759e3eb8aa6af359362765b51/retrofit/src/test/java/retrofit/RequestBuilderTest.java#L900-L913)

In the end, the message from the retrofit developers is:

*"Path replacements that span multiple path segments aren't going to be supported, you should use @Url to build the full relative URL programmatically if the number of path segments varies dynamically."*

So if you are in trouble with encode, the solution can be:

Your API for GET:

```
@GET
Call<Object> Function(@Url String path, @Query("CONTENT") String content);
```

Your API for POST:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST
Call<Object> Function(@Url String path, @Field("CONTENT") String content);
```

And you can call it with this:

```
String thePath = "www.foo.de/foo/foo2";
Call<Object> call = api.Function(thePath,content);
```

So with this you dont have the problem to encode something.

But if you are just looking for the normal encode in version 2.* the API has to be like this:

```
@GET("/{path}")
void example(@Path(value = "path", encoded = false) String path, ..);
```

Regards

Comment: Yes, they changed it from encode to encoded with 2.0.0

Answer (score 4):

Tested and its working now. 
Solution is just add encoded = true to make sure Proper url is hit.
eg:

```
@POST("{attendance_path}")
Single<Response> upLoadAttendence (@PartMap HashMap<String, RequestBody> postData,@Path(value = "attendance_path",encoded = true) String path);
```

Comment: this doesn't work when you contain the symbol `?` in the String path

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue and solve it as below code

```
 @POST(ApiKey.URL.add_edit_notice + "{id}")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<GenericResponse> callAddNotice(@Path(value = "id", encoded = true)  String id,
                                        @Field("user_id") String user_id,
                                        @Field("title") String title,
                                        @Field("description") String description,
                                        @Field("school_id") String school_id,
                                        @Field("filename") String filename);
```