# Access resource in decorator

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-resources, okhttp

I have some url resources:

```
<resources>
    <string name="base_url">https://my/base/url/</string>
    <string name="list_buildings_ressource">my/ressource</string>
</resources>
```

And I am using Retrofit to consume my API.

When I declare the service interface, I have something like:

```
public interface ApitrakService {

        @GET("my/resource/")
        Call<List<Building>> listBuildings();

    }
```

Question: how can I access the resource `list_buildings_ressource` in the decorator?

I have tried `getResources().getString(R.string.list_buildings_ressource)`, but it doesn't work as it has no context.

Comment: don't use resources to store constants.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833290/retrofit-path-replacements-replacement-over-whole-path-including

Comment: You need to use `@EncodedPath` and call the method using the resources that you load within a context.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Path`.

```
public interface ApitrakService {

    @GET("{myResource}")
    Call<List<Building>> listBuildings(@Path("myResource") String myResource);

}
```

To call you method with the custom URI, call something like this:

```
 String url = context.getString(R.string.list_buildings_ressource);
 apitrakServiceInstance.listBuildings(url);
```

Comment: I understand your design, but Retrofit will need to call this service as `ApitrakService service = retrofit.create(ApitrakService.class);` So I need to find a way to set my path in the interface.

Comment: Just to be clear: it would be OK to write `@GET("my/resource")`. I am just looking for a way to store my URL and resources in a separate file. (I am not mistaken the API/URL resource and the android resources.)

Comment: @VincentLê you can set the `base_url` via `retroficFactory`, But path is only allowed using this approach. You can't set dinamic content in this annotations.

Comment: @VincentLê You can try using AspectJ, but it seems to be too much thing to solve a simple problem.